# Dynamically assign CSS class to web site menu bar struts2

Tags: jquery, css, struts2

I want to dynamically assign CSS class to my web site menu bar

Header.jsp file

```
 <div class='menuArea'>
         <ul>

            <li class="current"><s:a action="listUsers">Users</s:a></li>
            <li><s:a action="listCustomers">Customers</s:a></li>
            <li><s:a action="searchItems">Items</s:a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Class "current" is applied to first li element and is static, but I want it to be dynamic depending upon the page selected.

`<s:include value="header.jsp"/>` is used to include header in other JSPs.

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing which page you are on on the client side?

Comment: No. Determining the page at client side would be very difficult since in my project there are more then 50 pages.

Comment: You're using jsp, so just build a function to handle the capture of the action using the `actionContext()` method, then make a switch statement for comparison and deliver a class based on any of the switch conditions being met. It's not magic.

Comment: You could look at Apache tiles, when it comes to adding things like you're doing it was built for just that task and it does a pretty good job of it. Somewhere you need to define what page gets what header... this is done in the tiles definitions. If is quite an efficient system for factoring commonality over many pages. The main benefit is that with includes you need to open JSPs (or whatever) to see what is being included. Tiles xml definitions are usually not so many they can all be in one file and provide a clear over arching description of how everything fits together(no/little digging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing parameter with `<s:include>` tag.

```
<s:include value="header.jsp">
  <s:param name="currentmenu" value="'page_id'" />
</s:include>
```

And then in your `header.jsp` retrieve parameter using `${param.your_param_name}` notation and set it to some variable which you can use inside `<s:if>` tag to set class to an element.

```
<s:set name="curr">
  ${param.currentmenu}
</s:set>

<ul>
  <li <s:if test="#curr == 'first_page_id'">class="current"</s:if> >
    <s:a action="listUsers">Users</s:a>
  </li>
  <li <s:if test="#curr == 'second_page_id'">class="current"</s:if> >
    <s:a action="listCustomers">Customers</s:a>
  </li>
  <li <s:if test="#curr == 'third_page_id'">class="current"</s:if> >
    <s:a action="searchItems">Items</s:a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your header.jsp, set a default var in the javascript:

```
<script>var currPage = "Users";</script>
```

then, in the main page, preferrably at the bottom, override:

```
<script>currPage = "Customers";</script>
```

then, in your footer, add some jquery:

```
    $("ul.menuArea > li").each(function(i, v){
     var $obj = $(this);
     if(currPage === $obj.find("a:first").text()){
      $obj.addClass("current");
      return false;
     }
    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kydun/